# Async with a function which does not return a value

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous

I am trying to use async to execute the unzipping of files. At the moment I'm getting a warning "The async method lacks 'Await' operators so will run synchronously."

When I try to call the ExtractAll function such as:

```
Await zip1.ExtractAll(sFolderExtracted, Ionic.Zip.ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently)
```

I am getting compilation error "`Expression does not produce a value`"

```
  Public Shared Async Function UnzipFile(sTempFolder As String, sZipFile As String, sRecordID As String) As Task(Of ExtractedFiles)

    Dim oExtractedFiles As New ExtractedFiles
    Dim TargetFile As String = sZipFile
    Dim sFolderExtracted As String = Path.Combine(sTempFolder, sRecordID) ' i.e. TEMP\12345

    Try
        Using zip1 As Ionic.Zip.ZipFile = Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Read(TargetFile)
            zip1.ExtractAll(sFolderExtracted, Ionic.Zip.ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently)

            'Populate ExtractedFiles class object with data about the extraction

            oExtractedFiles.sImageFront = GetImageBySide(sFolderExtracted, Cheque.ImageSide.Front)
            oExtractedFiles.sImageRear = GetImageBySide(sFolderExtracted, Cheque.ImageSide.Rear)
            oExtractedFiles.iRecordID = CInt(sRecordID)
            Return oExtractedFiles
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
           msgbox(ex.toString)
    End Try
End Function
```

How can I run the above code with async? Any ideas?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I meant await not async when calling the function. I will fix the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the library you are using for zipping, but it looks like `zip1.ExtractAll` is not an `async` method you can await.

It sounds like you want to offload the lengthy zip extraction operation onto a different thread, and await that. You can do that by wrapping the code you want to run on a different thread inside a call to [Task.Run](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194921(v=vs.110).aspx).

Try something like this:

```
 Public Shared Async Function UnzipFile(sTempFolder As String, sZipFile As String, sRecordID As String) As Task(Of ExtractedFiles)

    Dim TargetFile As String = sZipFile
    Dim sFolderExtracted As String = Path.Combine(sTempFolder, sRecordID) ' i.e. TEMP\12345

    Try
        Using zip1 As Ionic.Zip.ZipFile = Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Read(TargetFile)
            Return Await Task.Run(Function()
                                      zip1.ExtractAll(sFolderExtracted, Ionic.Zip.ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently)

                                      'Populate ExtractedFiles class object with data about the extraction

                                      Dim oExtractedFiles As New ExtractedFiles                                          
                                      oExtractedFiles.sImageFront = GetImageBySide(sFolderExtracted, Cheque.ImageSide.Front)
                                      oExtractedFiles.sImageRear = GetImageBySide(sFolderExtracted, Cheque.ImageSide.Rear)
                                      oExtractedFiles.iRecordID = CInt(sRecordID)
                                      Return oExtractedFiles
                                  End Function)
        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception
           msgbox(ex.toString)
    End Try
End Function
```

Also, consider renaming your function to make it obvious that it is an awaitable function.  Something like `UnzipFileTaskAsync`, or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to use async to execute the unzipping of files. At the moment I'm getting a warning "The async method lacks 'Await' operators so will run synchronously."

You can't use `async`/`await` to "force something to be asynchronous". Something is either asynchronous or it's not. I don't know if Ionic.Zip has an asynchronous API that you can naturally consume with `await`.

However (assuming this is a UI app), you can *pretend* something is asynchronous by running it (synchronously) on a thread pool thread. The correct tool here is called `Task.Run`.

First, make your synchronous method have a synchronous API:

```
Public Shared Function UnzipFile(sTempFolder As String, sZipFile As String, sRecordID As String) As ExtractedFiles
```

Then you can call it with `Task.Run`:

```
Await Task.Run(Function () zip1.ExtractAll(sFolderExtracted, Ionic.Zip.ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently))
```

Comment: Stephen, I am still getting the compilation error "Expression does not produce a value" with your proposed answer.